# Firefox Dev Tools highlight DOM nodes when clicking an element

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

To be clear, this is not highlighting in the sense of finding an element from the DOM Inspector to the page, or vice versa.  It's behavior I haven't seen before, but then I usually use Chrome.

I'm debugging a textarea that won't accept clicks, or allow selection, or basically gain focus in any way.  I noticed that clicking on the textarea, in the page, caused several DOM nodes in the Inspector to highlight, and then fade away after a second.  None of the nodes that highlighted were the textarea; they were parents of the textarea, including the body, but not necessarily all of the parents in between the textarea and the body.  There was also a sibling of one of the parents highlighted, as well.

It's one of those things where Firefox is trying to tell me something, but I don't know what.  I feel like the answer to my original problem is probably contained in this highlight, if only I knew what it meant.

In the attached screenshot, you can see the textarea highlighted in blue, being the selected element, and the rather grossly-colored highlights on a few other elements; this was right after I clicked on the textarea (in the page, like I was trying to enter some text in it; not in the inspector)
[image: screenshot of highlight]

What does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the nodes in the markup view (the thing in your screenshot) highlights, it means that these nodes have gone through mutations. These can be of the following manner:

- Attribute value change on the node
- Addition/Removal of child nodes

Now, what you are actually looking a way to hover the textbox and get the markup view to select your textbox, right ?

You can do that in two ways:

- Hit the shortcut Ctrl + Shift + C. You will see an overlay on the page which follows your mouse. Head over to text box and click it.
- Click the "Pick an element from the page" button on top left corner of the developer tools and the same node-selector will appear.

For more and deep information : visit the MDN page : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector

Comment: Thanks...I just needed the info on what causes the poo-colored highlights.